# How was the $n$-body problem solved before computers?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, perturbation-theory, history

Explaining the anomalous progression of Mercurys orbit was one of the first successes of general relativity. Given that a $n$-body problem is not solvable analytically even in the Newtonian picture (I've read about one solution that apparently needs millions of terms per small time step and so is infeasible) and even modern computers would struggle to detect such a small anomaly due to numerical errors, how was the anomaly originally calculated? And how did Einstein calculate the explanation with the significantly more complicated equations of GR?

Comment: You'll should read about [Urbain Le Verrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbain_Le_Verrier).  Short version : worked out using enormous amounts of dedication and hard work.

Comment: $n=2$ is sufficient for the case of the anomalous precession of Mercury. The following section in wikipedia is a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Precession_of_elliptical_orbits

Comment: In addition, you can find English translations of Einstein's paper on the subject online.

Comment: Seems to me this would be better suited on [hsm.se] than here, since it's more about the historical nature of problem solving in physics than physics concepts we typically cover here.

Comment: That the n-body problem is "unsolvable" is true, but only if we require the general long term solution. There is an infinite power series for the solution of the three body problem (it seems to converge so slowly as to be useless) and one can calculate n-body trajectories with classical perturbation theory in other ways than "just numerically". For certain scenarios (like the "stable" solar system) this a much more efficient than brute force numerical calculations.

Comment: Tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.  Asking for both the $n$-body problem and the GR precession of Mercury seems _too broad._

Answer (score 6):

This isn't relevant to the calculation of the precession of the perihelion of Mercury, but does address the title of the question.

In 1941, before computers and algorithms were up to the task, Erik Holmberg carried out N-body simulations of collisions between galaxies in 2 dimensions *in the lab*. He used the fact that both luminous intensity and gravitational force have an $r^{-2}$ dependence. N-body particles were replaced by light bulbs anchored to the lab bench and by removing light bulbs one at a time and measuring the luminous intensity at each location with a photocell, the "gravitational" force could be measured. Those forces were used in the time-integration of the system: the bulbs were literally moved across the bench according to their velocities and accelerations, assuming some time step. Did this involve lots of tedious book keeping? Almost certainly. But it was impressively accurate, the limiting factor turning out to be the tendency of the light bulbs to physically obstruct each other if the "resolution" of the simulation was increased by trying to add more bulbs. The final state of two of his simulations are illustrated in this figure:
[image: final states of two galaxy collisions simulated using light bulbs]

The details of the article and full text (without paywall) on [ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1941ApJ....94..385H/abstract). Unlikely that the link will ever break, but just in case the reference is Holmberg (1941) Astrophysical Journal, vol. 94, p.385.

Answer (score 2):

**Numerical methods existed well before computers** - e.g., [Newton's method for finding roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#History) was actually invented and used by Newton. Of course, using these methods was rather tedious and time-consuming, but still useful.

**Trigonometric tables, etc.**
[*Trigonometric tables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_tables), as well as tables of logarithms, exponents, typical definite integrals and likewise were compiled in abundance in XIXth century, with the explosion of engineering.

**Drafting rooms**
The scientific use in the first half of the XXth century, notably building nuclear weapons and satellites, required scaling up the computations. Although computers already existed, these were weak and expensive, so the actual computation was still done by hand - hundreds of people seated behind tables in drafting rooms, each calculating one point of approximation and passing it further to the neighbor:
[image]

**Mainframe computers** became widespread only since 1960s - to the extent that every research lab, university, or company could afford to have a computer. This still required carefully preparing calculations to make them efficient - e.g., transforming one's equations to dimensionless form, so that they could be solved ones, with the results applicable to multiple values of parameters.

Comment: I read that Einstein realized GR explained the anomaly within one week of finding the correct equations of GR. Did Einstein have access to hundreds of people to calculate his equations?

Comment: @Qni I don't know in which situation Einstein was at the time. I suspect though, that he simply analyzed the equations and perhaps eprformed some simple estimates. *Qualitative* analysis usually does not require extensive calculations - tese are more for *quantitative* analysis and engineering an actually working device. The problem is that today performing numerical calculations is so easy that people do not bother to analyze, understand or simplify their equations - I see in this community lots of people who diagonalize 2-by-2 matrices using Mathematica or take numerically simple integrals.